# android: How do I start animation from a certain point

Tags: android, android-animation

My Linear Layout takes around half screen width

I am using this code for translating

```
<translate
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
```

But my problem is the Linear layout translates from the end of the screen, where I have an another image at the end, so I don't want the layout to overlap with that image while animating

So I want it to start translating from left side of that image

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/row"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:padding="3dp"


                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/items"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:padding="3dp">
                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"

                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/search"
                    android:text="Android Custom Horizontal Dropdown Menu Icons" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"

                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/search"
                    android:text="Android Custom Horizontal Dropdown Menu Icons" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"

                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/search"
                    android:text="Android Custom Horizontal Dropdown Menu Icons" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"

                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/search"
                    android:text="Android Custom Horizontal Dropdown Menu Icons" />
</LinearLayout>
                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:id="@+id/widget"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                    android:paddingRight="16dp"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/three"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                    android:text="Android Custom Horizontal Dropdown Menu Icons" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

I want to animate the Linear Layout with id items
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that easily in Java code using [ViewPropertyAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) :

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.row); 
ll.animate().translationX(toX).setDuration(2000).setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
```

where (toX) is the float value where the LinearLayout will be moving to on the X axis of the screen. It will always start from the current position.

An alternative is the method :

```
ll.animate().translationXBy(byX);
```

which animates the LinearLayout **BY** the (byX) value.

Check the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html) for all available methods, you can do all kinds of animation with ViewPropertyAnimator.

Answer (score 2):

These are the following translations..

> Move from Top to Bottom

```
    android:fromYDelta="-75%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p"
```

> Move from  Bottom to Top....

```
    android:fromYDelta="75%p"
    android:toYDelta="0%p"
```

> Move from Right to left

```
    android:fromXDelta="75%p"
    android:toXDelta="0%p"
```

> try this .........**Left to Right** ........

```
<translate
    android:duration="2000"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:fromXDelta="-75%p"
    android:toXDelta="0%p"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
```

enjoy coding..........

Comment: This is for right flipping animation...What I did was left

Comment: you wanted top to botton ?? (means top to current postion)

Comment: actually I wanted it to start from centre of screen, not from end of screen, left to right only

Comment: I have a button at the end, I dont want it to overlap with that, so beside the button, it should start animating

Comment: so you wanted botton to current position ? Am i right ? or you can post your layout image and xml that is helping to solve fast ....

Comment: Nope, I want from right to left....But not extreme right, a little gap from screen